# Uncaught TypeError Cannot set property 'className' of null console output

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

i have this html code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="template-contactform-baggages-custom" name="baggages" value="baggages" class="sm-form-control" onchange="showcheck(this, numbag)" />
<div id="numbag" class="hidden">
    <input type="number" name="numofbag" value="" />
</div>
```

and this javascript function:

```
function showcheck(check, inputid) {

var checkid=check.id;
var checked=check.checked;
var inputelement = document.getElementById(inputid);

if(!checked){
    inputelement.className = "";
    inputelement.className = inputelement.className + "hidden";

}else{
    inputelement.className = "";
    inputelement.className = inputelement.className + "nothidden";

 } 

}
```

as you can see i want to hide or show my hidden div when i check my checkbox,
i think that everything is ok with my function but console has a different idea..!
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null, is the output

can anyone help me?

p.s. i made before a function with same logical and i have no problems

Comment: Check the value of `numbag` _variable_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
onchange="showcheck(this, numbag)"
```

Should be

```
onchange="showcheck(this, 'numbag')"
```

And you need to add a space when you are setting the className. BUT the issue is your code will keep adding classes so it will have both hidden and not hidden. You should use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```
inputelement.classList.toggle('hidden', !checked);
inputelement.classList.toggle('nothidden', checked);
```

And since you are just setting classes (missed the part where you clear it), you can just do a ternary operator.

```
inputelement.className = checked? "nothidden" : "hidden";
```

Comment: Man that's subtle. But of course, `numbag` will be an automatic global referring to the element, and `getElementById` will turn it into a string, and so it'll try to look up an element with the name `[object HTMLInputElement]` or `[object Object]` (depending on the browser), not find it, and... Nice one.

Comment: ok i forgot the ' ' when i call my function, thank you!
but the rest of my code works fine. when i check the checkbox class is nothidden and when i uncheck it class is change to hidden. so i have no problems with add more classes than one

Comment: AHH, I missed the line `inputelement.className = "";` so what you do on the next line is not needed. Just set the className to the class... The concatenation makes no sense. Updated it with a way you can set it without all that code.